# how to round a float number without using round()

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and got stuck with a problem. The problem is:

Write code that rounds a float number up or down without using the `round()` function introduced in Section 1.7. That is, write code that asks for a number, and then it takes that number and rounds it up or down appropriately without using round. For example, if the user types 3.6, the program should output a 4 since the fractional part .6 is greater than .5. The user were to type 3.2, the program should output a 3 since the fractional part .2 is less than .5.

So as I have learned that I can convert the float to an integer by calling the `int()` function, I have tried this:

```
num = float(input("Enter a float number: "))


if num >= .5:
    print(int(num) + 1)
else:
    print(int(num))
```

It kinda works, if I put `3.5` or `3.6` as input it gives me `4` but it gives me `4` even if I put `3.1` or `3.2` as input.

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example of `int` is a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are checking if the number is bigger than 0.5, rather than if the fractional part of the number is bigger than 0.5.

To find the fractional part of the number, subtract int(num) from num.

```
num = float(input("Enter a float number: "))

if num - int(num) >= 0.5:
    print(int(num) + 1)
else:
    print(int(num))
```

Comment: What does this do for negative numbers? (E.g., `-1.7`)

Comment: @MarkDickinson This does not work for negative numbers, you would compare the absolute value of the fractional part of the number and then subtract 1 instead of adding 1 if the number was negative for this to work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if num % 1 >= .5:
    print(int(num) + 1)
else:
    print(int(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
round_(10.4) # 10
```

### Convenience Function: `round_(num)`

```py
def round_(num):
    base = int(num)
    return base + (1 if (num - base) >= 0.5 else 0)

round_(10.4) # 10
round_(10.6) # 11
```

### Logic Explanation

```py
num = 10.4
base = int(num)
delta = 1 if (num - base) >= 0.5 else 0
rounded = base + delta
```

Answer (score 0):

The methodology that you used is logically correct, however the way you have implemented it is not exactly what you want to do.

When you say

```
num >= .5
```

You are checking if the number is greater or equal than `0.5`, you are **not** checking the decimal part.

However, if you subtract the float value with the int version of it you'll get the value you should compare.

Something like this

```
num - int(num) > 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: ")

def round(num):
  if num - int(num) >= 0.5:
    num = int(num) + 1
  else:
    num = int(num)
  return num
```